# Angular Material and input type 'time', value property vs ngModel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to split my incoming date object in 2 seperate mat-form-fields.

Firstly I create the DatePicker and give it the correct default value:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Datum laden: </mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="loadPicker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="data.mission.loadDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="loadPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #loadPicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

When I get to the time element it gets a bit tricky. Angular material doesn't seem to have a method of handling time. That means I have to revert back to the older method and just give my input field the type="time". Visually it works, giving it a value however doesn't seem to work when using the value property.

Could someone explain to me why using ngModel works but the other method doesn't?

Working version:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Tijd laden: </mat-label>
    <input matInput type="time" [(ngModel)]="test">
</mat-form-field>
```

test being:

```
test = `${this.mission.loadDate.getHours()}:${this.mission.loadDate.getMinutes()}`;
```

non-working version:

```
<mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Tijd laden: </mat-label>
            <input matInput type="time" value=`${data.mission.loadDate.getHours()}:${data.mission.loadDate.getMinutes()}`>
</mat-form-field>
```

Considering type="time" is handled by the browser. I would assume that both methods should work.

Comment: actually simple `value` is an html input attribute and for binding in `value` you need to use expression `value='{{value}}'`. or you can also use`[value]='value'`.

Comment: Could you translate this to my actual example. Normally only do backend so I am not home in the world of different bindings.

Comment: from above it seems like you want the date in `HH:mm` format? cant you use datepipe?

Comment: The only reason why I did it in that format was because the value parameter expects it that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: use this it will work, with value property `<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Tijd laden: </mat-label>
  <input matInput type="time" [value]="test">
</mat-form-field>`

Comment: @BjornPijpops if you are using `value` then it should be like `value='{{test}}'` and if you are using `[value]` then it should be like `[value]='test'.`. just see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kudott)

Comment: @FarhatZaman Is there a best practice? or are they all the same?

Comment: @BjornPijpops actually `value` is an html attribute and for binding with html attribute you need to use expression binding. while `[value]` is a DOM property which dont need expression bindings and on other side you don't need to use getHours and getMinutes. you can use date filter which is provided by angular. just see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4en3ep).

Comment: If you make an answer I would love to accept it as correct. The explanations and examples really helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually `value` is an HTML attribute and for binding with HTML attribute you need to use expression binding. while `[value]` is a DOM property that doesn't need expression bindings and on another side, you don't need to use getHours and getMinutes. you can use a date filter that is provided by angular. just see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4en3ep)